# How to send different-encoded data through same stream?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, tcp, stream

I wanna send images and texts from android client to Node.js TCP server.
You know the size of `data` in `'data'` callback in Node.js is unpredictable.

**My question** is how can the server separates images and texts?
I think it's impossible, so I will divide the stream(make another server) or
encode image using base64...but,

If you have any opinion, welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what, you will have to incorporate some sort of protocol. If you want to use binary as-is without encoding it, you will have to pick (or create) a protocol that supports that.

You could use something like WebSockets, but that only solves the framing problem. You still need to define your own message format (since IIRC WebSockets does not provide fields in its protocol for end user use). So with that in mind, you may as well just DIY.

One easy solution might be to create a TLV (Type-Length-Value) protocol. This kind of protocol is one where you have a type field, followed by a length field, and then a data field that is [length field value] bytes long. Make the fixed sizes of the type and length fields large enough to support your use case. As an example, you might have the type field be a single byte (allowing 256 message types), and have the length field be 4 bytes (allowing a single message to contain up to 4GB of data). Parsing these messages is simple: read 5 bytes, which gets you the type and length, then parse the latter 4 of the 5 bytes as an unsigned 32-bit integer, and then read that many bytes. You can buffer the data or stream it, whatever your need may be.

Comment: TLV.. it is very helpful hint! Thanks:)

Comment: But I wanted to minimize server processing because the server have to work like a proxy as many as possible.
I was just wondering...anyways, thanks!

Comment: I think TLV-style protocols are about as minimal as you can get. It's just reading 5 bytes, then n bytes, then repeat.